# Multi-column condition in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Let `DT` be a data.table:

```
DT <- data.table (col.1 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
                  col.2 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1),
                  #...
                  col.n = c(0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1),                
                  flag  = 0)

DT
    col.1 col.2 col.n flag
 1:     1     0     0    0
 2:     1     1     2    0
 3:     1     1     1    0
 4:     2     0     0    0
 5:     2     0     0    0
 6:     2     0     2    0
 7:     3     1     1    0
 8:     3     0     0    0
 9:     3     1     0    0
10:     3     1     1    0
```

How to set `flag = T` (or 1) where `col.1 + col.2 + col.n > 4`, without using the column names?

Comment: how about  `DT[,flag:=rowSums(.SD)>4,.SDcols=-"flag"]`

Comment: sorry, didn't see it was already answered, other possibilty below

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `Reduce`

```
DT[, flag := (Reduce(`+`, .SD)>4)+0L, .SDcols=-'flag'][]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DT[ , flag := fifelse(rowSums(.SD)>4, 1, flag)), .SDcols = !='flag']
```

Comment: You can modify the `ifelse` to `DT[, flag := ifelse(rowSums(.SD)>4, 1, 0), .SDcols= -'flag'][]`